# Revmob for corona issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk, revmob

I am trying to put revmob ads in my game. I downloaded the sample app and revmob SDK from revmob.com.
But I am getting an error every time I run the code.

The error says: "**Error loading module 'revmob' from file 'revmob.lua': *revmob.lua.218: '=' expected near '/'*** "

Please help with this?

I am using corona STARTER package, Build: 2104.2511.

Comment: `revmob.lua` has a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I think this is because I am using corona starter.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the one from the link below and did not get any error on the simulator. it seems you may have removed a character or misplaced it. Try to redo the process from the link.

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/corona.html

Comment: I tried with fresh download more than 5 times .. but every time I got the same error. P.S: I am using corona starter. Could this be a reason for such error?

Comment: I am using Adbuddiz with no problem. I doubt it could be problem although there might be bugs in it. I guess contact them directly. Adbuddiz responses to me very quickly. If you think they dont support you well dont waste your time. For android Adbuddiz runs very well but I had problem for iPhone which hadn't had chance to check.

Comment: What is the avg. eCPM rate you get for Adbuddiz?

Comment: Not quite sure, mine only had 600 views and showed eCPM about 12$ and earnings about $6. I havent really had a big hit yet as only developing for 6 month. Coming from civil engineering have a long way to go although already had an app downloaded 1000 times by engineers.